# actionscript 2 to 3 mouseX move on timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have an Actionscript 2 in Flash. I have used some times for moving in a timeline with mouse movement, I would like to convert it to Actionscript 3, have tried but are struggling:

```
var x_mouse = _root._xmouse;
var y_mouse = _root._ymouse;
if ( ( y_mouse >= 0 ) and ( y_mouse <= 400 ) ) {
  if ( ( x_mouse >= 0 ) and ( x_mouse <= 900 ) ) {
    this._parent.gotoAndStop ( Math.round ( x_mouse ) );
  }
  else if ( x_mouse < 0 ) {
    this._parent.gotoAndStop ( 1 );
  }
  else if ( x_mouse > 900 ) {
    this._parent.gotoAndStop ( 900 );
  }
}
```

Maybe it is a real easy task for you? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with, and it works perfect:

```
stop();
function findFrame(event:Event):void{
var frame:int = Math.floor((stage.mouseX/stage.stageWidth) * 900) + 1;
gotoAndStop(frame);
};
addEventListener("enterFrame",findFrame);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

At property panel, set instance name: "instance".

```
instance.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouse_handler);
function mouse_handler(event:MouseEvent):void {
   if (instance.mouseX < 0 || instance.mouseX > 900) {
      return;
   }

   instance.gotoAndStop(instance.mouseX);
}
```

I recommend you to use class files than timeline script.

Answer (score 0):

Some considerations:

as2 is **_parent**.  as3 is just **parent**.

**_root** in as3 is not the document root anymore, its only the timeline or document class of the swf the code is in.  For instance if you load a swf into another swf and call _root from the loaded swf, it only references that loaded swf's timeline or document class, not the containing swf's.

in as3 **stage** contains the mouse pointer location via the properties mouseX and MouseY.

Below is closer to what you are looking for:

```
var x_mouse = stage.mouseX;
var y_mouse = stage.mouseY;

if( y_mouse >= 0 && y_mouse <= 400 )
{
    if ( x_mouse >= 0 && x_mouse <= 900 )
    {
        this.parent.gotoAndStop( Math.round ( x_mouse ) );
    }
    else if ( x_mouse < 0 )
    {
        this.parent.gotoAndStop( 1 );
    }
    else if ( x_mouse > 900 )
    {
        this.parent.gotoAndStop ( 900 );
    }
}
```